# npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11

Tags: npm, next.js, core-js

When I enter `$ npm install --save react react-dom next`, I got this warning:

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained
>   and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please,
>   upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

I tried updating it with `$ npm install --save core-js@^3`, but it shows the same error.

How can I update core?

Comment: Using "$ npm --depth 9999 update" will update top level package, also recursively inspect all dependencies. npm update: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm uninstall core-js` then `npm i core-js` should work.